# How to create a Google Assistant app which you don't have to ask for?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

How do I create a Google Assistant app? Where I don't have to ask the assistant to talk to the app. 
I don't know further how to explain it, so just comment if you have any question!

Do you have to be a "Partner" with Google or is this something I myself can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance in how to ask a good question. Updating your question to provide examples of what you're looking for, what you've tried, and specific problems you've encountered will help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SDK to create an app in any language you choose. You choose how you will trigger and send queries to the assistant, you don't necessarily have to "talk to it".

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/

You don't have to be a partner with Google as long as you use it for development purposes only. You are not allowed to commercialize what you build without permission from Google.